# Mongodb returning wrong count

Tags: mongodb, count, distinct

I streamed data from a data file that is a few GB and imported into a Mongo collection. The file was zipped so I did  `zcat file.gz | mongoimport`  I know that I should be having 454229 documents in the collection. It was empty and the file has 454229 records. After the process, I tried a count and got 459680. I emptied the collection and repeated the process. Same result. Then I tried a distinct on the "_id" column, tried length, and got 454229. To makre sure no other process was changing the data, I tried count and distinct twice, distinct followed by count and then count followed by distinct.

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.amazon_xml_data.distinct("_id").length;
454229
rs1:PRIMARY> db.amazon_xml_data.count({});
459680
rs1:PRIMARY> db.amazon_xml_data.count({});
459680
rs1:PRIMARY> db.amazon_xml_data.distinct("_id").length;
454229
```

Mongo version is 3.2.22. I have this text at the end of the log file too...

```
amazon_xml_data 1.11GB
2020-02-15T14:37:07.302+0530    imported 454229 documents
```

So I am almost sure that the number returned by count is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2 cases `count` may be inaccurate:

> After an unclean shutdown of a mongod using the Wired Tiger storage engine, count statistics reported by count may be inaccurate.
>   Run [validate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/validate/#dbcmd.validate) on each collection on the mongod to restore the correct statistics after an unclean shutdown.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown

> On a sharded cluster, `db.collection.count()` can result in an ***inaccurate*** count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters

Use better:

```
db.amazon_xml_data.aggregate(
   [
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I executed validate and now it is showing the correct count.